# Failed to export all rows in attribute table in ArcMap to .dbf

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, export, dbf

I would like to export a large attribute table to .dbf format, which includes almost 5,000,000 rows. But the exported table only contains about half of the rows without showing any error message during export progress. I am wondering if there is a size limit for exporting attribute table in ArcGIS.

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include either the fields defined in the dBase file or the sum of the widths of those fields.  It would also help to describe the exact procedure you used to do the export.

Comment: something that has worked for me when I've had problems exporting to .dbf tables, is export the attribute table to a geodatabase table, and then export that to .dbf format. i have no idea why it worked, or if it will help you, but it's worth a try

Answer (score 3):

.dbf files do have a size limit, but it isn't necessarily the number of rows.  It's  a disk size limit of 2GB.  If you have a lot of attributes, the 5,000,000 rows could make the .dbf quite large.

Perhaps you might want to remove some unnecessary attributes.  Or split the file into parts.

Alternatively, try looking at other file formats.